Absolutely convergence of the series $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}}$
I am trying to find if the series $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}}$$ converges absolutely or not.
Let's try to find $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}:$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n+3\right)!!}{\left(4n+4\right)!!}}}{\left(-1\right)^n\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}}}=\left(-1\right)\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}{\left(4n+4\right)\left(4n+2\right)}}$$
Then we have $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\ \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}{\left(4n+4\right)\left(4n+2\right)}}=1,$$ and therefore the ratio test is inconclusive.
Let us also try to see what the Raabe-Duhamel’s test gives: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n+4\right)\left(4n+2\right)}{\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}}-1\right)=\frac{1}{5}\lim _{n\to \infty }\ n\left(\frac{\left(4n+4\right)\left(4n+2\right)}{\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}-1\right)$$
May someone explain to me why the last equality holds? How did we get rid of the radical in the limit?

Why not just remove the $(-1)^n$ and ask about the convergence of the series? Removes a lot of noise from the question.

$$(1+x)^{1/5}=1+\frac15x+O(x^2)$$ for $|x|<1.$ Here $x=\frac{(4n+4)(4n+2)}{(4n+3)(4n+1)} -1=\frac{8n+5}{(4n+3)(4n+1)}\sim\frac1{2n}.$

@ThomasAndrews, I am not really familiar with the big-o notation, but I have just read about it on wikipedia. So are you writing that equality when $x\to\infty$?

How could it be for $x\to\infty,$ when I say it is true for $|x|<1,$ and the $x$ I specifically wrote, $\sim 1/(2n),$ which means it goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty.$

@ThomasAndrews, I still don't understand how this allows as to factor out a $\frac{1}{5}$ out of the limit, and leave the minus $1$.

@ThomasAndrews, in our case I should write $$\left(1+\frac{8n+5}{\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}=1+\frac{8n+5}{5\left(4n+3\right)\left(4n+1\right)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$ right?

As noticed in the comments they used binomial first order exapansion, as an alternative using Striling's approximation we have that
$$\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}=\frac{(4n)!}{2^{4n}((2n)!)^2}\sim\frac{\sqrt{8\pi n}\left(\frac{4n}e\right)^{4n}}{2^{4n}(4\pi n)\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{4n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

$2/\sqrt 8=1/\sqrt2.$ Not really important, but ...

@ThomasAndrews Nicer of course! Thanks

If you know the central binomial rule, $$\binom{2m}m\sim\frac{4^m}{\sqrt{\pi n}},$$ you can skip around the Stirling formula approximations and cancellations.  (But, of course,  Stirling is the basic proof of that.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient?wprov=sfti1#Asymptotic_growth

@ThomasAndrews Thanks a lot! I didn’t know this other way. I’ll keep it in mind.

Too long for a comment.
Start with $$\frac{(4 n-1)\text{!!}}{(4 n)\text{!!}}=\frac{\Gamma \left(2
   n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma(2 n+1)}$$Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation twice, divide by $5$, exponentiate and finish using Taylor series.
Thus
$$\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}}=\frac 1 {{(2\pi n)^{1/10}}}\Bigg( 1-\frac{1}{80 n}+\frac{1}{12800
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Bigg)$$
Doing the summation, we than have the zeta function $$\left\{\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{10}\right),\zeta
   \left(\frac{11}{10}\right),\zeta
   \left(\frac{21}{10}\right),\cdots\right\} $$ Using the above truncated series and converting the result to decimal would give
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n\sqrt[5]{\frac{\left(4n-1\right)!!}{\left(4n\right)!!}}\sim -0.427269$$ while the "exact" summation would give $-0.427359$.
Edit
Palying with the number $k$ of terms used in the expansion of the summand
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \text{summation} \\
 1 & -0.434588 \\
 2 & -0.426989 \\
 3 & -0.427275 \\
 4 & -0.427372 \\
 5 & -0.427366 \\
 6 & -0.427358 \\
 7 & -0.427358 \\
 8 & -0.427360 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
